# Let TexStudio play .wav after compiling finished

Tags: compiling, texstudio, audio

I'd love to have my Texstudio play a sound (.wav) after it finished compiling. Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343937/how-to-put-a-video-inside-a-beamer. It says somewhere in the question "Recompile Texstudio with the option PHONON=true"... So possibly somewhere you have that option or you need a new installation with that option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On easy possibility would be to instruct TXS to call some external program of your choice to play the sound. Some examples of suitable programs are `afplay` or `vlc` (the later is probably overkill just to play some sound).

To add this to the compilation, open your texstudio preferences and edit the "Build and View" command (or whatever command you use to compile you document)

[image]

- For example on a mac I compile with `latexmk`, open the .log and .pdf and afterwards play the audio:

  ```
  txs:///latexmk | txs:///view-log | txs:///view-pdf | afplay <path to audio file>/quack.wav
  ```
- For windows (thanks to @user1805743 !)

  ```
  txs:///compile | txs:///view | powershell -c (New-Object Media.SoundPlayer "C:\Windows\Media\notify.wav").PlaySync();
  ```

Comment: ah that looks good so far, but i need to play abit: i have win10, trying now to get vlc to start via command line....
next step:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC>vlc.exe "<path>\Windows 98 Sound Chord.mp3"

Comment: @user1805743 For windows https://superuser.com/questions/101974/play-a-sound-maybe-wav-from-windows-line-command might also be interesting.

Comment: thanks for hetting me on the right track. i finally solved with the following line in the build & view:
txs:///compile | txs:///view  | powershell -c (New-Object Media.SoundPlayer "C:\Windows\Media\notify.wav").PlaySync();

Comment: @user1805743 Good to hear you got it working! Would you mind if I include this information in my answer?

Comment: no, please go ahead!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `quack.wav` instead of `notify.wav`? ;-)

Comment: @marmot Corrected this inexcusable mistake! Next step would be to automatically select the sound based on which tikzling is compiled :)

Comment: Dangerous. It might then happen, depending on the tizkling, that the compiler decides to hibernate. ;-)

Comment: @marmot This happens anyway everytime I forget a `;` in tikz :)

Comment: upgrade question: how to get notified after failure: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450113/let-texstudio-play-wav-after-compiling-failed