# Let TexStudio play .wav after compiling failed

Tags: texstudio, compilation-error

I just found out how to get reminded once TexStudio finishes compiling, see [this question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450015/let-texstudio-play-wav-after-compiling-finished/450017#450017)
But how do i achieve the same thing when TexStudio doesn't manage to compile? To be more specific, I dont need a notification for every "process ended with failure", but only if TexStudio aborts its efforts.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can hook onto the `app.hasLatexErrors` function via a script, and call this script after every command run (like `txs:///compile`).

On Windows, create a user macro with trigger `?after-command-run`:

```
%SCRIPT
if (app.hasLatexErrors()){
    system('cmd /C "powershell -c (New-Object Media.SoundPlayer "C:\\path\\to\\sound\\file\\sample.wav").PlaySync();"')
}
```

Note the double `\\` to escape backslash in the path.

Comment: thanks. ill have to look up how do to scripts with texstudio